# R: Compute number of rows in data frame that have 0 colSums for specific columns using a function

Tags: r

I have a data frame with `n` rows and `m` columns where `m > 30`.

My first column is an `age` variable and the rest are medical conditions that are either on or off (binary).

Now I would like to compute the number of observations where none of the medical conditions is switched on i.e. the number of healthy patients. I thought I could use the `rowSums` function to count observations wherever the row sum is zero (of course excluding the age variable) but I tried some functions and did not succeed.

Here is an example how it could work but always involving a lot of AND / OR statements which is not practical. I was looking for a non-loop solution.

```
example <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=c(40,1,1,1,36,1,0,1,56,0,0,1,43,0,0,0), nrow=4, ncol=4, 
byrow=T, dimnames <- list(c("row1","row2","row3", "row4"),c("Age","x","y","z"))))
```

Two impractical alternatives to arrive at desired outcome:

```
nrow(subset(example, x==0 & y==0 & z==0))
table(example$x==0 & example$y==0 & example$z==0)
```

What I actually wanted is sth like this:

```
nrow(example[rowSums(example[,2:ncol(example)])==0])
```

Comment: `rowSums` is fine for this: `rowSums(example[, -1])` gives the number of "medical conditions" per row, and `sum(rowSums(example[, -1])==0)` gives the number of rows where all medical conditions are `0`. Use `na.rm=TRUE` within `rowSums` if there might be NA values in some cells.

Comment: I knew it was trivial. Did not think about the sum of rowSums. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, if nested code isn't working as you'd expect, try evaluating it bit by bit, from the inside out. For example, for your `nrow(example[rowSums(example[, 2:ncol(example)])==0])`, you could try (1) `example[, 2:ncol(example)]`, (2) `rowSums(example[, 2:ncol(example)])`, (3) `rowSums(example[,2:ncol(example)])==0`, (4)   `example[rowSums(example[,2:ncol(example)])==0]` and finally (5) `nrow(example[rowSums(example[,2:ncol(example)])==0])`. You would discover that step 4 returns a 4-row data frame, and you're only interested in those rows for which the value is 1. `nrow` is insufficient.

Comment: Thanks for that! I still have to get used to breaking down my thoughts for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
apply(example[, -1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) all(x == 0))
##  row1  row2  row3  row4 
## FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Here you are applying `FUN` on every row of the `example[,-1]`. It gives you logical vector indicating which rows satisfy the condition that all of the variables in that row are equal to 0. You get this by using `all` function inside your `FUN` argument function.

You can use this result to get rows containing all healthy patients or those containing atleast 1 non healthy patient.

```
example[apply(example[, -1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) all(x == 0)), ]
##      Age x y z
## row4  43 0 0 0

example[!apply(example[, -1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) all(x == 0)), ]
##      Age x y z
## row1  40 1 1 1
## row2  36 1 0 1
## row3  56 0 0 1
```

And you can get number of healthy rows or otherwise as below

```
# healthy rows
sum(apply(example[, -1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) all(x == 0)))
## [1] 1


# rows with atleast one unhealthy condition
sum(!apply(example[, -1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) all(x == 0)))
## [1] 3
```

Comment: Note that this is much slower than `rowSums` for large matrices. For a 100000 x 10 matrix, `microbenchmark` suggests 286 ms versus 3 ms.

Comment: @jbaums : I agree it might be slower, my intention is to provide more generic solution for the problem.

Comment: Point taken, and +1 for the clear and detailed answer.

Comment: Wow, that is powerful. Although kind of looping through every row I like the flexibility of it. Of course will be much slower in my data frame :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just want the total numbers of observations/rows that satisfy this condition right? Then you can use -

```
nrow(example[example$x==0 & example$y==0 & example$z==0,])
```

Else, if you want to use rowSums, this will work -

```
nrow(example[rowSums(example[,2:4])==0,])
```